# How to draw path for given lat long values

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing an map activity in that i have draw a path in the given points i have refered the coding from the below link in works great,
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/#comment-885831

But it show the path when touch on the map ,it shows me the path where touch between two points,but in oncreate itself i have to show the path.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call this method at onCreate.

```
 private void getPath(){

     float sourceLat = yourSourceLatitude;
     float sourceLng = yourSourceLongitude;    

     float descLat = yourDescLatitude;
     float descLng = yourDescLongitude;


     LatLng origin = new LatLng((int)(sourceLat * 1E6), (int)(sourceLng * 1E6));
     LatLng dest = new LatLng((int)(descLat * 1E6), (int)(descLng * 1E6));    

    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);     
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
    downloadTask.execute(url);
    }
```

To camera animation:

```
private void CamView(float descLat, float descLng)
{
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(descLat, descLng)).zoom(12).build();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Call this method at `onPostExecute()`;

Please go through some good tutorials for google maps integration.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,While copied this method my GeoPoint is not importing

Comment: Sorry. You have to use `LatLng` instead of `GeoPoint`. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i have to set the camera view how can i do that

Comment: See the edited answer. And go through some good tutorials.